# Array of integers from file

Tags: ruby, string, int

I am trying to grab large numbers from a file, store them as an array, and add them up.

```
nums = Array.new
x, total=0, 0
file = File.open("inputfile.txt", 'r')
while !file.eof?
  nums[x] = file.readline
  x+=1
end

while x>0
  x-=1
  total += nums[x]
end

puts total
```

When my code executes, I get an error saying:

```
String can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)
```

I checked to make sure that each array element actually has the right data in it. I think that the numbers are considered strings when stored. If that's the case, how would I change the array to integers so I can total them up?

Comment: If the file contains all numbers, I can golf this: `puts IO.readlines("inputfile.txt").map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just modify

```
nums[x] = file.readline
```

to

```
nums[x] = file.readline.to_i
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate line-by-line over an opened file:

```
total = File.open("inputfile.txt").inject(0) { |sum, line| sum + line.to_i }
```

Also see the example in the comment from squiguy, using `map` and `reduce`.

Comment: Interesting... I would have expected it to be `File.open("inputfile.txt").read_lines.inject(0)` but I guess `read_lines` is implicit?

Comment: @AlexanderWallaceMatchneer Good question, but I wouldn't describe it that way. `read_lines` reads the whole file and gives you a data structure -- namely, an Array of every line. By contrast, `open` gives you a File instance, **which is iterable** in a line-by-line fashion. That's why it can be pipelined directly into inject, without creating a bulky data structure (the Array of all lines).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
total = 0
File.foreach("inputfile.txt") { |li| total += li.to_i }
puts total
```

Storing a large array in memory isn't a good idea because you can fill your available memory before your code can calculate a sum. Instead, read the file line-by-line and calculate as you go.

Benchmarks show that line-by-line I/O is as fast as reading an entire file into memory and then trying to process it as single lines, so use the more conservative `IO.foreach` or `ios.each_line` to avoid filling memory needlessly.